# Enviar parametros a SQL de tipo tabla para realizar un insert de un carrito de productos

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedure

he realizado un proyecto en donde un cliente puede agregar elementos a un carrito y realizar un pedido, y una vez echo esto se inserte dicho pedido en la base de datos, el problema es el siguiente, realice una tabla en SQL para poder tomar los datos que le voy a pasar en una Data Table, pero me da un error de desbordamiento al querer realizar la inserción de los datos en SQL a través de un Stored Procedure.
Este es el error ( Error de desbordamiento aritmético al convertir numeric al tipo de datos numeric. Se terminó la instrucción. ) y el siguiente es el codigo que estoy usando en C#.

```
public int InsertarDatosEnLista(DataTable tblParametros,string nombreProcedimiento)
    {
        SqlTransaction transaccion;
        SqlConnection conexionSQL = new SqlConnection(strConexion);
        conexionSQL.Open();
        transaccion = conexionSQL.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nombreProcedimiento, conexionSQL, transaccion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var parameter = new SqlParameter //Esta declaracion es Clave en este Metodo
            {
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                ParameterName = "DTItems", 
                Value = tblParametros
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            int filas = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return filas;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conexionSQL.Close();
            conexionSQL.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Aqui esta la DataTable que se envia al Stored Procedure

```
        DataTable dtPedido = new DataTable();

        dtPedido.Columns.Add("idUsuario", typeof(int));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("idProducto", typeof(int));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(int));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("Talle", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario", typeof(decimal));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("PrecioTotal", typeof(decimal));
```

Y aqui el codigo que tengo para la Tabla y el Stored Procedure

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TipoProducto] AS TABLE(
    [idUsuario] [int] NULL,
    [idProducto] [int] NULL,
    [Cantidad] [int] NULL,
    [Talle] [char](5) NULL,
    [PrecioUnitario] [decimal](18, 2)NULL,
    [PrecioTotal] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
)


Create PROCEDURE insertarPedido

    @DTItems AS [dbo].[TipoProducto] READONLY

AS 
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Pedidos]  (idUsuario,idProducto,Cantidad,Talle,PrecioUnitario,PrecioTotal)
    SELECT * FROM @DTItems

END
GO
```

Comment: El tipo `decimal` de c# no está siendo compatible con tu definición de `decimal(18,2)` porque este último tiene un tamaño fijo. No veo otro desbordamiento. O no estás restringiendo el valor de la columna del DataTable a lo que soporta en la bd

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo de los datos que intentas insertar y que te dan error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar el error, era el tipo numeric tenia que cambiar la , por el . para que la base de datos la tome como tal, gracias por el interes! Asi que tuve que almacenar el tipo decimal en un string para luego realizar un replace en c# y despues realizar un Convert(Numeric(18,2),PrecioUnitario) y lo mismo con PrecioTotal en la base de datos.
El codigo en la base de datos quedo asi

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TipoProducto6] AS TABLE(
[idUsuario] [char](255) NULL,
[idProducto] [char](255) NULL,
[Cantidad] [char](255) NULL,
[Talle] [char](255) NULL,
[PrecioUnitario] [char](255) NULL,
[PrecioTotal] [char](255) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertarPedido]

@DTItems AS [dbo].[TipoProducto6] READONLY

AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Pedidos]  (idUsuario,idProducto,Cantidad,Talle,PrecioUnitario,PrecioTotal)
SELECT CONVERT(INT, idUsuario) AS idUsuario,
       CONVERT(INT, idProducto) AS idProducto,
       CONVERT(INT, Cantidad) AS Cantidad,
       CONVERT(CHAR(5), Talle) AS Talle,
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), PrecioUnitario) AS PrecioUnitario, 
       CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),PrecioTotal) AS PrecioTotal 
FROM @DTItems
END
```

Y la DataTable seria esta

```
DataTable dtPedido = new DataTable();

        dtPedido.Columns.Add("idUsuario", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("idProducto", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("Cantidad", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("Talle", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("PrecioUnitario", typeof(string));
        dtPedido.Columns.Add("PrecioTotal", typeof(string));
```

Comment: deberias actualizar tu pregunta, y no colocar en la respuesta otra pregunta

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu respuesta y cerrar la pregunta, así además obtendrás máss reputación